How to show the grid in the xy plane in a 3d matplotlib plot
I want to plot a circle in 3d. To have a feeling of the 3 dimensionality, I want to not show any axis or grid, except the grid in the xy-plane. I figured out how to get rid of the z-grid but I also want the grid only in the xy-plane and no labels of all the axes. I have now
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Draw a circle
radius = 1
center = (0, 0, 0)
num_points = 100
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_points)
x = center[0] + radius * np.cos(theta)
z = center[1] + radius * np.sin(theta)
y = center[2] * np.zeros_like(theta)

ax.plot(x, y, z, color='b')

ax.view_init(elev=20, azim=30)
ax.set_zticks([])

ax.xaxis.line.set_color((0, 0, 0, 0))  # Transparent color
ax.yaxis.line.set_color((0, 0, 0, 0))  # Transparent color
ax.zaxis.line.set_color((0, 0, 0, 0))  # Transparent color

plt.show()

It results in:

